# Textarea with ngModel get overwritten in a ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular

I just started working on an Angular project.
In the following code, I would like to use `ngFor` and `ngModel` to iterate an array and put the item value as a default  value for the text area. And I have an example with two values in the array, all the textareas are always get overwritten by one of them instead of showing the different values on the website. Does anyone know what could be possible reason for that?

```
      <mat-form-field *ngFor = "let item of model.answers; let index = index;" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Cluster Answer</mat-label>
        <textarea
          matInput
          id="{{item['id']}}"
          rows="7"
          placeholder="Cluster answer"
          [(ngModel)]="model.answers[index]['answer']"
          name="clusterAnswer"
          formControlName="clusterAnswer"
        ></textarea>
        <mat-hint>Define the cluster answer to be suggested</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: try [(ngModel)]="item.answer"

Comment: I have tried [(ngMdoel)]="item.answer", it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

you must define the value in the form builder in the ts non in the html:

```
exampe.formBuilder{
test:[defaultValue]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you already have ngModel so no need to specify formControlName, use of [(ngModel)] with formControlName has been deprecated

```
    <mat-form-field *ngFor = "let item of model.answers; let index = index;" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Cluster Answer</mat-label>
            <textarea
            matInput
            [id]="item['id']"
            rows="7"
            placeholder="Cluster answer"
            [(ngModel)]="model.answer"
            ></textarea>
            <mat-hint>Define the cluster answer to be suggested</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide different name attribute value for each individual iteration because the ngModel value uses the value of the name attribute to connect the new control with the provided name to the form.

In your case it's not even necessary to use two way data binding (the bananna in a box [(ngModel)]) because you already have the state of the form inside the form itself so you can just use the [ngModel] to bind the value if there is one and whenever you want to get the new values you can either use `@ViewChild(NgForm) form: NgFrom` in order to get the form from your view (probably its going to be better to query it using a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) name. It will look something like `<form #f="ngForm">` where `f` is your template variable. Also check out the [View Child Decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)) or inside the ngSubmit event of your form you can provide the value of the form using a template variable. `<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitHandler(f.value)">`.

I don't recommend using the two way data binding because what happens is that we store the same values at two different locations:

- the state of each individual ngModel control that we have
- inside the state your component.

Also formControlName directive comes from the Reactive-Forms and it's not good to mix both types of forms inside a single form.

```html
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let item of model.answers; let i = index;" class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Cluster Answer</mat-label>
    <textarea
       matInput
       [id]="item['id']"
       rows="7"
       placeholder="Cluster answer"
       [ngModel]="model?.answers?[i]?['answer']"
       [name]="'clusterAnswer' + i"
    ></textarea>
  <mat-hint>Define the cluster answer to be suggested</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```